# Jsp page not hitting the servlet files being mapped by the use of web.xml

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my project,the jsp page is mapped to the servlet using the web.xml file.Here is a part of the code regarding the same :
    
        register
        box.RegisterServlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Am using apache tomcat 7.0 .When i try to open this page /Registration,it gives me a 404 error.In the box folder,i have all the servlet files(.java and .class).
Also,on trying to compile the servlet files seperately using javac tool,it says that the packages javax.servlet.* and javax.servlet.http.* are not found.
So,the question is:

1. How do i make sure that jsp page can access the servlets so that they can hit the database?
2. What to do to make sure that the servlets can be compiled using the javac command?

Comment: The error specifially says :The requested resource (/yaman/proj/Registration) is not available.

Comment: have a look at servlets wiki page of ours  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

you can compile your Servlet class (say MyServlet.java) with the following like command,

`javac -classpath .;path\tomcat\common\lib\servlet-api.jar;path\to\mylib*.jar -d classes src\web\MyServlet.java`

Better you use any build tool like ant or maven to compile, package or deploy your web application.